# Receiving UDP packets through firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, udp

I have an embedded device which communicates over UDP (and occasionally TCP/IP) with an application on a host computer.

The embedded device continuously emits UDP packets to a fixed IP address (the one of the host) and a fixed port. The host PC has to open its firewall on that port to allow the incoming UDP traffic.

Now I wonder whether there is a way to circumvent the firewall, so that the user does not need to explicitly disable the firewall on that given port.

Since the application on the host is waiting for the UDP packets from the embedded device, could it somehow "initiate" the communication? I.e. sending once an outbound packet and then receiving the UDP messages as response to this outgoing communication? So that the firewall thinks these incoming UDP packets are requested by the application on the host (which they are, in fact) and thus allows them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but complicated setup. The technology is called UPnP. If the router/firewall connected to Host supports UPnP, then the application can be developed to dynamically open the Port on the router and accept incoming connections.